# Каким образом реализовать верно пограничный случай?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию (я 2 написал одна другой помогает) которая принимает массив произвольной длины, и ещё одно значение. Функция должна возвращать новый массив той же длины, но значения должны быть пропорциональны второму значению. Пример передано [10, 10], 10 получено [5, 5]. Значение после массива (10) можно представить как вес который мы можем взять с рынка после покупок, а значение в массиве как какие то товары, нам нужно брать пропорционально всего что есть, в зависимости от количества товаров. Значение в результате должны быть целыми.

Первый If это моя корявая попытка побороться с пограничным значением в котором у меня выдавался массив с ошибкой, если его (первый If) убрать то получится рабочая функция но которая выдаёт ошибку в след. случае - передаём [1, 1], 1 получаем [1, 1], а должны [1, 0].

Скажите как правильно прописать "заглушку" для данного случая. Спасибо.
В первом цикле я неверно записываю значение в topNum т.к. я записываю туда номер индекса наибольшего значения, а затем сравниваю номер индекса и другие значения... к сожалению я не придумал как мне одновременно в теле цикла записывать и наибольшее значение чтобы сравнивать его с другими значениями в массиве и индекс массива с текущим наибольшим значением... (мало опыта я зелёный совсем)

```
    const sumArr = (something) => {
    let sum = 0;
    let i = 0;
    while(i < something.length) {
        sum += something[i];
        i += 1;
    } 
    return sum;
};

const result = (arr, weight) => {
    let fullSum = sumArr(arr);
    const onePercent = weight / fullSum;
    let arrResult = '';
    let i = 0;
    if (weight === 1) {
        let topNum = 0;
        let newArr = 0;
        i = 0;
        while(i < arr.length) {
            topNum = (arr[i] > topNum) ? i : topNum;
            i += 1;
        } while (i < arr.length) {
            newarr += (i === topNum) ? 1 : 0;
            i += 1;
        } return newArr;
    }
      else if (fullSum >= weight) {
        while(i < arr.length) {   
            arrResult += (i === arr.length - 1) ? `${Math.round(arr[i] * onePercent)}` : `${Math.round(arr[i] * onePercent)}, `;
            i += 1;
        }
    } else if (fullSum < weight) {
        return arr;
    }
    return arrResult; 
};
```

Comment: Сейчас 30 градусов и пятница - мозги у нормальных людей самоотключились для отдыха. Поэтому, если Вы хотите получить ответ - переписывайте вопрос на понятном языке. Что такое " 2 аргумент"? - это второй аргумент?.Нужно экономить не время написания вопроса, а время людей, которые читают вопрос и могут ответить.

Comment: то есть нужно, чтобы сумма элементов была равна числу которое передали туда?

Comment: нет, вы приходите на рынок и хотите купить всех товаров что там есть, но в зависимости от того, сколько вы можете унести с собой. Если вы не можете забрать все товары то должны взять каждого по чуть чуть в зависимости от ваших возможностей, если же товаров [5, 10, 12, 6, 8] а вы можете унести только 1 то в данном случае должно быть ответом [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: @Mark, почему для `[5, 10, 12, 6, 8]` ответ `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`, а не `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` например?

Comment: потому, что меньше единицы мы не можем вывести число, а по пропорции 12 самое больше в массиве, у него выше всего пропорция, попробуйте уберите первый if из моей функции, а else if который идёт следом сделайте if, и поэксперементируйте с другими значениями отличными от единицы, всё будет корректно работать

Comment: @Mark, по какой пропорции?

Comment: Вот например разные входные данные 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cbc6suk2rhgie0/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202019-06-21%2022.23.56.png?dl=0

и то в последнем примере ошибка короче шляпу я походу сделал полную :(

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал алгоритм так. Считаем решение в дробных числах и переводим его в целые. Получившиеся дроби округляем вниз. Считаем сколько целых чисел ещё нужно добавить. И добавляем +1 в элементы с максимальными дробными остатками.

```js
const sumArr = (something) => {
    let sum = 0;
    let i = 0;
    while(i < something.length) {
        sum += something[i];
        i += 1;
    } 
    return sum;
};

const result = (arr, weight) => {
    let fullSum = sumArr(arr);
    const onePercent = weight / fullSum;
    let arrResult = [];
    let ves_ostatkov = [];
    for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        arrResult[i] = Math.floor(weight*arr[i]/fullSum);
        ves_ostatkov[i] = ((weight*arr[i]/fullSum)-arrResult[i]);
    }
    let fullSum2 = sumArr(arrResult);
    for (i=0;i<(weight-fullSum2);i++) {
        let max_ostatok=ves_ostatkov[0];
        let num_max=0;
        for (j=1;j<ves_ostatkov.length;j++) {
            if (max_ostatok<ves_ostatkov[j]) {
                max_ostatok=ves_ostatkov[j];
                num_max=j;
            }
        }
        ves_ostatkov[num_max]=0;
        arrResult[num_max]++;
    }
    return arrResult; 
};
```

Comment: Возможно веса остатков нужно пересчитывать по какой нибудь сумме квадратов отклонений. Но это уже из разряда перебора всех вариантов. Тк не скажу какой тогда алгоритм нахождения оптимального варианта.

Comment: Спасибо но всё равно не все случаи работают :(
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jmd3ygrcn0mrar/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202019-06-22%2007.32.29.png?dl=0

Comment: Я думал что так и надо. Так тут просто условие добавить в начале что если weight больше или равно fullSum, то вернуть arr как результат.

Comment: у меня добавлено такое условие на коде выше, в любом случае спасибо отправил уже на проверку объяснил что не удалось самостоятельно все пограничные случаи "порешать" жду вердикта. Скинул и ваш код с пометкой что не мой, а делал более опытный коллега, для сравнения так сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```js
function result(arr, weight){
 var w; //вес который мы можем отдать за раз
 arr=arr.map((v,i)=>[i,v]).sort((a,b)=>a[1]>b[1]?-1:1).map(v=>[v[0],0]); //добавляем индексы с которым был передан массив arr, сортируем его по убыванию и обнуляем значения
 while(weight>0){ //пока есть еще вес, который можно отдать
  w=(w=~~weight/arr.length,w<1?1:w); //определяем отдаваемый вес (для сокращения количества циклов)
  arr.every(i=>{weight-=w; i[1]+=w; return weight>0?true:false;}); //раздаем вес каждому, если еще остался
 }
    return arr.sort((a,b)=>a[0]>b[0]?1:-1).map(v=>v[1]); //делаем обратную сортировку массива в соответствии с переданными индексами и отрезаем индексы
}
result([1,1],1);
```